# Using abbreviations in mathematical writing

Tags: education, article-writing

I'm currently writing my bachelor's thesis, and I am using the term "independent and identically distributed" a lot. I was wondering if it is accepted if I abbreviate this to "i.i.d.". Or if I can write something like "from now on I will denote this as 'i.i.d.'".

Because the papers I have been reading do not abbreviate it. So I was unsure about whether this is accepted or not.

Thank you.

Comment: In general there is no problem with this, as long as it's clear. However it might depend on your supervisor, so it's always good to check things up with him/her,

Comment: This is indeed a common abbreviation, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17391/what-are-i-i-d-random-variables). Even better, you define it properly: A random variable $X$ is called "i.i.d." ...

Comment: My recommendation is that you ask, not complete strangers, but the professor who is supervising and will be judging your thesis!